# how to repair: pop up under youtube video on iframe tab

Tags: iframe, youtube, popup, layer, facebook-iframe

My problem is:

There are an embedded youtube video in iframe Page Tab and when I click share button the pop up appear under the youtube video and I cant see the pop up. How solve this problem?
Link to fan page tab https://www.facebook.com/NashaFanStranica?sk=app_315095505174563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe `?wmode=opaque` and search around... as it's not clear if it should be `wmode=opaque` or `wmode=transparent`

opaque will seem fine in most browsers, though

Comment: Thank you. I solved that problem another way. I add 'display: popup'.